# c - properly free memory of a struct

Tags: c, memory

My struct named `Table` holds an array of a struct named `Object`. Object holds a pointer to another `Object`. I want to make two methods - one that frees an `Object` and one that frees a `Table` when pointers to these structs are given (`ObjectP` and `TableP` respectively):

This is my current naive implementation which absolutely doesn't work since valgrid is spitting warnings all over the place (i'm really new to c coming from Java):

```
/*
 * Represents a linked list containing a key value
 */
typedef struct Object {
    void *key;
    struct Object *top;
    struct Object *next;
    Boolean originalCell;
} Object;

/*
 * Represents a table that stores keys based on a given object's hash
 */
typedef struct Table{
    Object *linkedObjects;
    size_t size, originalSize;
    HashFcn hfun;
    PrintFcn pfun;
    ComparisonFcn fcomp;
    Boolean wasDuplicated;
} Table;

void FreeObject(ObjectP object)
{
    free(object);
}

void FreeTable(TableP table)
{
    free(table);
}
```

How should i properly free these structs?

EDIT:

This is how i allocated the variables:

```
ObjectP CreateObject(void *key)
{
struct Object *object = (struct Object*) malloc(sizeof(struct Object));
...
}

TableP CreateTable(size_t tableSize, HashFcn hfun, PrintFcn pfun, ComparisonFcn fcomp)
{
    struct Table *table = malloc(sizeof(Table));

    if (table==NULL)
    {
        ReportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }

    table->linkedObjects = NULL;
    table->linkedObjects  = malloc(tableSize * sizeof(Object));
...
}
```

Comment: What's an example of the warnings you're seeing?

Comment: Can you show how you allocate them as well please?  Typically deleting the objects should involve as many calls to `free` as construction had to `malloc`

Comment: What is `top`? Is it the first element?

Comment: Are you trying to drop objects separately from the table as a whole?  If so, you have a major problem because for each object in the middle of the list that is deleted, there is a prior object that has a pointer to the object being deleted which becomes a dangling reference.  You really need to find that object and fix its next pointer to point to the object that the next pointer of the object being deleted points to.  If you're only deleting a whole table, then life is a whole heap easier!  (_Sorry_ pun intended.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler only deleting the whole table :)

Comment: @simonci edited my question and added the allocation.

Comment: @AdamSznajder yes it is the first element (top of the stack)

Comment: @Tom Thanks.  It looks like `table->linkedObjects` is an array of `Object` instances.  Are the `top` and `next` members of `Object` used?  Do they point to data that containing `Object` owns?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a linked list or a vector? For a linked list, you wouldn't have this: `table->linkedObjects  = malloc(tableSize * sizeof(Object));` And for a table you wouldn't need  `next`pointers in your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I dislike your `ObjectP` and `TableP` notation; I'm going to make the pointers explicit with `Object *` and `Table *`.*

From a comment, you're only concerned with deleting a whole table; that's good because it is a lot simpler than deleting an arbitrary object.

I'm assuming that the `tableSize` parameter to `CreateTable()` is stored in `table->size`.

```
static Object *FreeObject(Object *obj)
{
    Object *next = 0;
    if (obj != 0)
    {
        free(obj->key);   // If you allocated this
        next = obj->next;
        free(obj);
    }
    return(next);
}

void FreeTable(Table *tab)
{
    if (tab != 0)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tab->size; i++)
        {
            Object *next = tab->linkedObjects[i].next;
            while ((next = FreeObject(next)) != 0)
                ;
            free(tab->linkedObjects[i].key);  // If you allocated this
        }
        free(tab->linkedObjects);
        free(tab);
    }
}
```

The `FreeObject()` function is static because it is only intended for use by `FreeTable()`.  It deletes the key, assuming that the key was allocated when the object was allocated; it captures the pointer to the next item in the list (which may be a null pointer), frees the object itself, and returns the pointer to the next item.

The `FreeTable()` function uses the `FreeObject()` function to release all the objects in the linked object lists hanging off the objects allocated in the array named `linkedObjects`, then deletes the array of objects, then deletes the table.

The key thing when freeing memory is to ensure that there is one free for each and every allocation, and only one free for each allocation.  The value passed to `free()` must be a value from `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.  Remember that a `realloc()` can change the address of a previous allocation, but the value from `realloc()` must be freed rather than the original allocation from `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to delete the whole table (along with the objects), you need to walk your object graph and call `free()` for each block allocated via malloc, i.e. one `Object` or one array of these.

I understand your object graph looks like this:

[image: Graph]

Then the way to delete is:

```
void FreeObjectChain(Object* obj) {
    Object* curr = obj->next;
    while (curr) {
        Object* tmp = curr;
        curr = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

and

```
void FreeTable(Table* table) {
    for (int i=0; i<table->size; ++i) {
        FreeObjectChain( &(table->linkedObjects[i]) );
        // or simply FreeObjectChain( table->linkedObjects + i );
    }
    free(table->linkedObjects);
    free(table);
}
```

Comment: You're close, but I think there's a problem in the way you use `FreeObjectChain()`.  The trouble is that you'll try to free each element of the array in `table->linkedObjects` separately (which is not a good idea).  I think you need to pass `table->linkedObjects[i].next` to `FreeObjectChain()` to avoid the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but please note that my `FreeObjectChain` starts from `obj->next` which should also avoid the problem you mentioned. (The way you're suggesting might look more natural though)

Comment: OK — yes; you're right.  That fixes the problem.  You're OK; my comment is irrelevant/inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do something like that:

```
void freeObject(Object* obj) {
    if (obj->next != NULL) {
        freeObject(obj->next);
    }
    if (obj->key != NULL) {
        free(obj->key);
    }   
    free(obj);
}

void freeTable(Table* table) {
     for (int i=0; i<table->size; ++i) {
         freeObject(&(table->linkedObjects[i]));
     }
     freeObject(table->linkedObjects);
     free(table);
}
```

Comment: i usually don't like recursive functions, but it makes perfect sense here... assuming no loops... but if loops are possible you would have to also nil out obj->next

Answer (score 0):

FreeTable() must traverse the array and call free() on all the objects.

You should first know/learn how a computer works at low-level scope before attempting any code which deals with memory management.